# Databinding layout inside include tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-include

I'm trying to use data binding for dynamic layout binding. For example:

```
<include
        layout="@{item.getLayoutRes}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Assuming that `item` object defines `getLayoutRes` method, marked with `@LayoutRes`, that provides an `int` describing a layout to inflate.

Looks like this is not supported yet, or the syntax is different?

Comment: I don't think that would be supported. As ids will be dynamic and layout files are generated at compile time..